# dojox mobile datepicker and switch not working using dojox mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo, dojox.mobile

I binded the value attribute of dojox.mobile.Switch to a property in model using dojox.mvc.at. when i changed the property in model, the Switch responds to the changes; but when i changed the state of switch, the property in the model s not getting updated.

Same is the problem with dojox.mobile.DatePicker.

I'm using dojo 1.9.0

Can any one help with this issue?

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="switch"></label>
    <div id="switch" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Switch" data-dojo-props="leftLabel: 'ON',rightLabel: 'OFF', value: at(appContent,'switch')" onStateChanged="alert(this.value)"></div>
</div>
```

and my mdoel object is

```
require(["dojox/mvc/getStateful",
         "dojox/mobile/TextBox",
         "dojox/mobile/ValuePickerDatePicker",
         "dojox/mobile/DatePicker",
         "dojox/mobile/Opener",
         "dojox/mobile/TabBarButton",
         "dojox/mobile/RadioButton",
         "dojox/mobile/TextArea",
         "dojox/mobile/Slider",
         "dojox/mvc/Output",
         "dojox/mobile/Switch"],
        function(getStateful){
            var data={
                    'switch':'on'
            };
            appContent=getStateful(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those widgets have separate issues. The way [dojox/mobile/Switch](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/Switch.html) class is composed with [dojo/_base/declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html) does not work well with how [dojox/mvc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc.html) extends [dijit/_WidgetBase](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetBase.html), which is the base class of most of widgets. You’ll need to apply the extension explicitly to [dojox/mobile/Switch](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/Switch.html) to work around that issue, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['base']"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojox/mvc/atBindingExtension",
                "dojox/mobile/Switch"
            ], function(atBindingExtension, Switch){
                atBindingExtension(Switch.prototype);
                require([
                    "dojo/Stateful",
                    "dojox/mvc/at",
                    "dojox/mobile/parser",
                    "dojox/mvc/Output"
                ], function(Stateful, at, parser){
                    window.at = at;
                    window.model = new Stateful({
                        state: "off"
                    });
                    parser.parse();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Switch" data-dojo-props="value: at(model, 'state')"></div>
        <div>Switch state: <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Output" data-dojo-props="value: at(model, 'state')"></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[dojox/mobile/DatePicker](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/DatePicker.html) does not send user’s input back to the `value` attribute. You’ll need to watch for each slot’s change and update `value` attribute manually to work around that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['base', 'DatePicker']"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/aspect",
                "dojo/date/locale",
                "dojo/date/stamp",
                "dojo/Stateful",
                "dojox/mvc/at",
                "dojox/mobile/parser",
                "dojox/mobile/DatePicker",
                "dojox/mvc/Output"
            ], function(array, aspect, locale, stamp, Stateful, at, parser, DatePicker){
                window.at = at;
                window.model = new Stateful({
                    date: stamp.toISOString(new Date())
                });
                aspect.after(DatePicker.prototype, "startup", function(){
                    var self = this,
                        slots = this.slots;
                    array.forEach(slots, function(slot){
                        self.own(slot.watch("value", function(){
                            var pattern = slots[0].pattern + "/" + slots[1].pattern + "/" + slots[2].pattern;
                            self._set("value", stamp.toISOString(locale.parse(slots[0].get("value") + "/" + slots[1].get("value") + "/" + slots[2].get("value"), {datePattern: pattern, selector: "date"})));
                        }));
                    });
                });
                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/DatePicker" data-dojo-props="value: at(model, 'date')"></div>
        <div>Date picker value: <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Output" data-dojo-props="value: at(model, 'date')"></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Best, - Akira

Answer (score 0):

i tried with the changes you mentioned for dojox.mobile.Switch, but it was not working. It is still one way binded(from model to view) and not view to model. I went through the Switch.js file and found that the way the 'value' attribute is updated is not the way the mvc would trigger. I manually added three lines of code in dojox/mobile/Switch.js, two lines in _onClick function and one line in _changeState and the switch is working fine with mvc and with out mvc also. Are these changes valid??

```
_changeState: function(/*String*/state, /*Boolean*/anim){
```

> this._set("value", state);   */ Added by me */

```
        var on = (state === "on");
        this.left.style.display = "";
        this.right.style.display = "";
        this.inner.style.left = "";
        if(anim){
            domClass.add(this.switchNode, "mblSwitchAnimation");
        }
        domClass.remove(this.switchNode, on ? "mblSwitchOff" : "mblSwitchOn");
        domClass.add(this.switchNode, on ? "mblSwitchOn" : "mblSwitchOff");
        domAttr.set(this.switchNode, "aria-checked", on ? "true" : "false"); //a11y

        var _this = this;
        _this.defer(function(){
            _this.left.style.display = on ? "" : "none";
            _this.right.style.display = !on ? "" : "none";
            domClass.remove(_this.switchNode, "mblSwitchAnimation");
        }, anim ? 300 : 0);
    }


_onClick: function(e){
        // summary:
        //      Internal handler for click events.
        // tags:
        //      private
        if(e && e.type === "keydown" && e.keyCode !== 13){ return; }
        if(this.onClick(e) === false){ return; } // user's click action
        if(this._moved){ return; }
     // this.value= this.input.value= (this.value == "on") ? "off" : "on";  removed by me
        this.input.value = (this.value == "on") ? "off" : "on"; //added by me
        this._set('value', this.input.value);                   //added by me
        console.log("clicked and this.value "+this.value);
        this._changeState(this.value, true);
        this.onStateChanged(this.value);
    }
```

I checked twice and there is no issue with the normal behaviour and also works fine with mvc. if these changes are valid, please make these changes in next version to support mvc.

Comment: I see, looks that it makes sense, though I'm not an owner of dojox/mobile. You may want to enter a ticket to bugs.dojotoolkit.org.